# A HTML to PDF converter button using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

The PDF generator button in my html webpage is not working. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

I am using jquery version 1.7.2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Print Fax View</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Deflate/adler32cs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/libs/Blob.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/basic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF("p",in,"a4");
            var source = $('#target').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(source, 0.5, 0.5, {
                'width': 7.5,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body id="target">
         <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
         <div> <p>Hello World </p> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not generating anything.
Thanks in advance

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery"></script>

Comment: @diegocr I didnt understand... I have included that line.

Comment: The jquery file is called jquery? not jquery.js? You need to spend more time writting the question. You completely missed doing any debugging, is there any errors, warnings in the console?

Comment: No warnings in console...Sorry I will be more descriptive now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am also beginner for html, javascript. Here is the corrected, which is generating pdf.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Print Fax View</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.cell.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.ie_below_9_shim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf/jspdf.PLUGINTEMPLATE.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var source = $('#target').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(source, 0.5, 0.5, {
                'width': 75,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body id="target">
         <button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
         <div> <p>Hello World </p> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ksved In fact, you just need one of the dist files (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/master/dist) but certainly your jquery file missed the .js extension, which apparently was causing the problem.