# How to Convert Html Page in webview Android to pdf And Share Pdf Without using 3rd party library

Tags: android, html, android-intent, webview

How to Convert`.html` Page  in `webview` android to `.pdf` so that i can share it via email or any other app `WhatsApp`,`Bluetooth`,`etc...`

Comment: u have to use javascript library like jspdf. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991718/a-html-to-pdf-converter-button-using-jspdf

Answer (score 0):

```
u have to use javascript library like jspdf.
```

Here is an example [A HTML to PDF converter button using jspdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991718/a-html-to-pdf-converter-button-using-jspdf)
more about jspdf : 
https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html